# Adding DataColumn to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to move the data from a `dataColumn` to a specific column in my `dataTable`. I am not sure how to specify what column within my `Datatable` I want to add the `datacolumn`.

```
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            dt1.Columns.Add(col);
        }
```

I receive an exception `Column 'X' already belongs to another DataTable.`

Comment: Are you just wanting to add the _column_ (meaning a column with the same name and type) or move the _data_ from one table to another?

Comment: Move the data from one table to another.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to copy the properties like `ColumnName` and create new `DataColumns`:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    dt1.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
}
```

There's a reason for the `ArgumentException` when you add a `DataColumn` which already belongs to another DataTable. It would be very dangerous to allow that since a `DataTable` holds a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) to their columns and every column holds a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.table.aspx) to it's DataTable. If you would add a column to another table your code would blow sooner or later.

If you also want to copy the `DataRows` into the new table:

```
foreach (DataRow row in t1.Rows)
{
    var r = t2.Rows.Add();
    foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
    {
        r[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
    }
}
```

Comment: So that replicates the column name and datatype. How would I extract the data from the col to the datatable?

Comment: So what is your actual question? Do you want to copy the schema of a DataTable or do you want to copy (also) all `DataRows`?

Comment: Copy all of the data into a seperate data table. I want to be able to specify which columns i copy the data to.

Comment: @escobar_season: Edited my answer to show how you could copy also the data(only the columns which you have added to the table previously).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add a DataColumn from another table, because it already has an association with it's original table and a DataColumn is passed by reference to the Add method because it's an Object. You'll have to copy it. Here's one way you can do that:

```
public static class DataColumnExtensions
{
    public static DataColumn CopyTo(this DataColumn column, DataTable table)
    {
        DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn(column.ColumnName, column.DataType, column.Expression, column.ColumnMapping);
        newColumn.AllowDBNull = column.AllowDBNull;
        newColumn.AutoIncrement = column.AutoIncrement;
        newColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = column.AutoIncrementSeed;
        newColumn.AutoIncrementStep = column.AutoIncrementStep;
        newColumn.Caption = column.Caption;
        newColumn.DateTimeMode = column.DateTimeMode;
        newColumn.DefaultValue = column.DefaultValue;
        newColumn.MaxLength = column.MaxLength;
        newColumn.ReadOnly = column.ReadOnly;
        newColumn.Unique = column.Unique;

        table.Columns.Add(newColumn);

        return newColumn;
    }

    public static DataColumn CopyColumnTo(this DataTable sourceTable, string columnName, DataTable destinationTable)
    {
        if (sourceTable.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        {
            return sourceTable.Columns[columnName].CopyTo(destinationTable);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The specified column does not exist", "columnName");
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable tableA = new DataTable("TableA");
        tableA.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
        tableA.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));

        DataTable tableB = new DataTable("TableB");

        foreach (DataColumn column in tableA.Columns)
        {
            column.CopyTo(tableB);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is also an extension method that can be used to Copy individual columns by name, i.e. `tableA.CopyColumnTo("Column1", tableB);`.

Then you can copy the data like this if the new table is an exact copy of the original:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tableA.Rows)
{
    tableB.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Or in a way similar to the second piece of code in Tim Schmelter's answer if it is not an exact copy. I would, however, recommend some error checking if you aren't copying all the columns into the new table:

```
foreach (DataRow souceRow in sourceTable.Rows)
{
    DataRow destinationRow = destinationTable.Rows.Add();

    foreach (DataColumn destinationColumn in destinationTable.Columns)
    {
        string columnName = destinationColumn.ColumnName;

        if (sourceTable.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        {
            destinationRow[columnName] = sourceRow[columnName];
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a normal behavior, if you're adding the same column to more than one DataTable ArgumentException will be thrown.

see documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55b10992.aspx

you can create a new column same as the one you already added to the original table and add it to the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Table data is organized by row, then by column.  You can't (that I know of) add a column of data in one shot.  You will need to add the column *definition* to the second table and add the data to it separately.

Since your original code looped through all columns, you may be better off copying the original datatable using `DataTable.Copy()` and deleting what you *don't* want.